# Twitter Open Authentication with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to provide login using google/facebook/twitter. All three are configured with the following urls for authorize concent redirects:

- **google**: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
- **facebook**: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
- **twitter**: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize

When a redirect happens, following params are added:

```
client_id=
redirect_uri=
response_type=
state=
scope=
```

Both **google** and **facebook** are happy with it and show a login screen (if you are not logged in) or the consent screen.. happily everafter!

But **twitter** seems to be upset, says: ***Whoa there!
There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we need from applications asking to use your Twitter account. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake.***

Sample Url: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=3698443421GbH3698443421hj&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/connect/twitter&response_type=code&state=V2aPvq

Why?

Comment: Did you try to request the token first?

Comment: My Bad, Twitter is still on 1.0a while fb and google are on 2. From Twitter docs: Note that **OAuth 1.0a** is still required to issue requests on behalf of users.